# Authentication using Middleware in route api (solved)

Tags: php, laravel, api, rest

i wanted to do authentication inside api.php in laravel, i use custom middleware to identify Auth()->role.

this is what i have done:

[image: Middleware UserRole]
[image: route api.php]

my problem is, when i logged on as author it said not authorized(which i have declare the route in route api.php). but, when i use admin, it works well

[image: this is the response when i logged in as author]

EDIT:
the only problem is i use whitespaces when i declared the role, like this
[image: whitespaces on role]

the answer is to delete the whitespaces as referred to Waad Mawlood answer below

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply used

```
auth()->user()->role
```

instead of

```
$request->user()->role
```

⚠️ do not leave white spaces between roles => `admin,author`